# Having trouble with text processing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-processing

I have run into an odd syntax which I'm trying to coerce into something a bit more python friendly.

Given a structure like this:

```
s = "a1{b2{a3|b3}c2{d3|e3}e2{a4}}b1{a6|b7}"
```

After processing the text you should end up with:

```
data == {
    'a1': {
        'b2': ['a3', 'b3'],
        'c2': ['d3', 'e3'],
        'e2': 'a4'},
    'b1': ['a6', 'b7']
}
```

I'm struggling with this and would like some assistance on how to correctly parse this out.  Obviously the example is just that an example, but the tokens of "|","{","}" are the right splitters.

```
def parse_tree_to_dict(data):

    level, word, key, tree = 0, "", "", []
    index_tree = []
    result = {}

    for letter in data:
        if letter == "|":
            print("{0} {1} {2}".format(" "*level, "|", word))
            tree.append(word)
            word = ""
        elif letter == "{":
            print("{0} {1} {2}".format(" "*level, "{", word))
            key = word
            index_tree.append(key)
            word = ""
            level += 1
        elif letter == "}":
            print("{0} {1} {2}".format(" "*level, "}", word))
            key = key if key else word
            result[key] = tree if len(tree) else word
            try:
                result = result[index_tree.index(key)-1]
            except (KeyError, IndexError):
                pass
            level -= 1
        else:
            word += letter
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = "a1{b2{a3|b3}c2{d3|e3}e2{a4}}b1{a6|b7}"
    data = parse_tree_to_dict(s)
    assert data == {
        'a1': {
            'b2': ['a3', 'b3'],
            'c2': ['d3', 'e3'],
            'e2': 'a4'},
        'b1': ['a6', 'b7']
    }, "Nice try.. {} is wrong".format(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of thing where you'd really want a full parser generator to do the work for you. There's a bazillion parsers for Python (that is, for use in Python, not to parse Python code) out there, but alas, nothing in the standard library. I don't have much experience with any of them, but it's definitely worth checking out: parsing is not something to be done ad-hoc if that can be avoided. (See https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing.)

Failing that, you should consider writing a recursive-descent parser. Your grammar, unless I miss my guess, can easily be formulated without left recursion, making a recursive descent parser straightforward to write. Each term function in your parser would return a data object, to be used by the term function which called it. Not too difficult, and it would have the advantage of not requiring a separate tokenization pass.

Comment: Done - now I'm stuck on the recursion component - same place ;)